# Python Json search for value and sum up

Tags: python

Suppose i have json like

```
{ 
   "name":"Land cruiser, Toyota "
   "rate":"98"
 },

 {
   "name":"Triton, Mitsubishi"
   "rate":"96"
 },
 {
    "name":"l200, Mitsubishi"
    "rate":"98"
 },
 {
    "name":"Hiace, Toyota"
    "rate":"98"
 }
```

all i want is to search Toyota in name and sum up all the rate

Example:

```
#load json here
def getSum(lastname):
     #search and sum calulation
      return resutl
getSum('Toyota')
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your json is a list of objects, that you've read into the variable `l`:

```py
def get_manufacturer_sum(l, manufacturer):
    return sum([int(d["rate"]) for d in l if manufacturer in d["name"]])


toyota_sum = get_manufacturer_sum(l, "Toyota")
```

Comment: i loaded my json like this 

with open('cars.json', 'r') as f:
    mdata = json.load(f)

my json ID is datas
i used for loop to get all datas